# How to get a sorted list from this dictionary with conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have this dictionary in (Python 3.x) :

```
dict = {
    "Gryffindor": gryffcount,
    "Ravenclaw": ravencount,
    "Hufflepuff": hufflecount,
    "Slytherin": slycount
}
```

`gryffcount`, `ravencount`, `hufflecount` and `slycount` are `int` variables.

And I want to output a list in which :
- the first item should be the key for which the value is the highest
- the second one should be the key for which the value is the second highest 
- and so on...
EDIT : but if two counts are equal then the one that was mentioned first in the dictionary should appear first.

So if gryffcount == 0, ravencount == 2, hufflecount == 0, slycount == 4

I should get this list :

```
["Slytherin","Ravenclaw","Gryffindor","Hufflepuff"]
```

Comment: Assuming your dictionary is “dct”: sorted_keys = map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted(dct.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

Comment: Did you mean `["Slytherin","Ravenclaw","Gryffindor","Hufflepuff"]`?

Comment: yes, and I fogot to add an additional condition. I just edited the question

Comment: Hi I took time to answer your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196310/fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-and-quaternions) don't delete it without showing you understood and render thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it

```
sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True)
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming `dict` to `my_data` to avoid clashing with the builtin `dict`:

```
my_data = {
    "Gryffindor": gryffcount,
    "Ravenclaw": ravencount,
    "Hufflepuff": hufflecount,
    "Slytherin": slycount
}

# create a new dictionary, sorted by value
# For Python 3.6+ if you're using CPython, or any version of Python 3.7+
my_data_sorted_by_value = dict(sorted(my_data.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

# older Pythons:
import collections
my_data_sorted_by_value = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(my_data.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

# and here are the keys
print(list(my_data_sorted_by_value.keys()))
```

Comment: what makes you think dict(sorted_data) stays sorted?

Comment: In CPython 3.6+, they are ordered; in Python 3.7, they're ordered as part of the spec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: But good point; added clarifying comments and a variant that works in older Pythons.

Comment: not everybody uses cpython 3.7. and you should mention that in your answer.

Comment: also, result should be a list of keys, not dict.